# Add one property and Multiply another property using a Javascript Reduce

Tags: javascript, reduce

```
var modifiers = [
    { plus : 2, times : 2},
    { plus : 0, times : 1.2},
    { plus : 10, times : 1},
    { plus : 1, times : 1.7},   

];
```

If I wanted to add all the pluses and multiply all the timeses together I could do it in a loop like this

```
function calc(modifiers) {
    var plus = 0;
    var times = 1;
    for (var mod of modifiers) 
    {
        plus += mod.plus
        times *= mod.times
    }
    return plus * times
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using a single reduce, or would I have to do 2 reduces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use the object as the accumulator and return a summary object with both values:

```js
var modifiers = [
    { plus : 2, times : 2},
    { plus : 0, times : 1.2},
    { plus : 10, times : 1},
    { plus : 1, times : 1.7},   

];

let summary = modifiers
    .reduce((a, {plus, times}) => 
      ({plus: a.plus + plus, times: a.times * times}))
console.log(summary)
```

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz -- I wasn't paying attention to that. Edited.

Comment: absoloutely awesome thank you but i think to make it truely like the top it should be console.log(summary.plus * summary.times), this is really going to help me understand how reduce works thank you I will analyse this